# JQGrid url action not firing when using Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Fires the action when I'm using Html.BeginForm but not Ajax.BeginForm.  Anyone know why?

Comment: When I use Html.BeginForm, the URL get from the JQGrid fires as expected.  This does not happen at all for a JQGrid within a Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: RailRhoad ... could you put your code here? I need to see how to use that load function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason being was that the jQuery.JQGrid() I had being called via a $(document).ready(function(){} located in the partial.  This executes via a normal post but in an ajax post, this function doesn't get fired.  Instead I had to place it in a load function that gets called after the OnSuccess of the Ajax form.  Works like a charm now!